# Calling an Array through URL

Tags: php, arrays, url

I'm looking to call an array through a URL, and I have looked through the questions but from what I've seen they're all for creating a url from an array/something of that sort.

I'm a bit new to HTML and such, but I can read and understand a decent amount.  What I'm trying to do is make a shortcut on a website that allows me to call an array through the URL.

I get an error saying I can either use an int or an array, but I haven't found if I need a certain value in the url or I'm just calling the array the wrong way.  I know how to make one in java/javascript and C++, as well as calling via code, but not through URL like it's saying I can.

Reason I'm looking to do this is get something done at a faster pace, and all at once instead of one by one.  I'm using Google Chrome, and the website uses yuigen, as well as javascript, but the URL doesn't direct anything through PHP thatI know of.

Comment: I read this twice and still don't know what you mean.  A URL is just a string.  So, you could pass characters down to it that could be split INTO an array.  But the URL itself is one dimensional.

Comment: Yeah, I'm puzzled as well because of that.  I'm assuming that the way it would be done is through the integers in the array, but calling them through the URL is something I'm not familiar with at all.  

I'm thinking it is in a similar way to call an array through code, but I've looked through the source multiple times and haven't found anything relating to the array I would want called.

Comment: It would be like:  http:\\this.com\?thisArray=1|2|5|6|10|5  Then grab that element and split at the pipe.

Comment: You can have an array in a url, sort of. It would be something like example.com/?a[b]=1&a[c]=2. In PHP, these could be accessed by using $_GET['a']['b'], and $_GET['a']['c'];

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you want to take a URL like this:

```
http://this.com/?thisArray=1|2|5|6|10|5
```

and get an array of the values in `thisArray`. Just do this:

```
$theArray = explode('|', $_GET['thisArray']);
// now, $theArray is a PHP array: [1, 2, 5, 6, 10, 5]
```

`$_GET['thisArray']` accesses your URL parameter, and `explode('|', ...)` splits it on the pipes.